# WPF Colors different from images and web

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I've been creating custom color resources in my WPF apps and the colors in the WPF form do not match the original colors from the images.

[image: Wpf Colors Inconsistent]

In the above I have chosen a blue color at random, and made a form with that color as its background. Source code below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid Background="#2E4272">

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

I'm trying to identify the root cause and I'm getting a strange phenomena that I will try to explain. So, first I took an image with a color I liked and used the eye dropper tool in adobe illustrator to determine its color. Then I used that color in my WPF form. They didn't match so I put the two next to each other and did a screen capture.

I then opened that screen capture in illustrator and the part from WPF gave me the right hex value (the same as the original image) and if I put them next to each other they look the same. The part of the screen capture that was the original logo is some other color. So...if I take a screen capture from my computer the WPF color get turned back to the right color and the original color gets changed to something else.

Comment: Where in the image is the original color? I did some digging and couldn't find the color that you used in WPF. That said, the color of the window does not look anything like the color you specified.

Comment: I recreated your 'code' and it displays a very different shade of blue. There must be something wrong with your desktop (color depth, graphics card)

Comment: Does the color from WPF match the color from this site: http://paletton.com/#uid=13M0u0kloljaJvYg4qDqIfZw7aE

Comment: is there some process I should be following to correct my display color?

Comment: No it does not match because the website's palet says that it uses  #2E4172 instead of #2E272 but even then the color in the browser is not that. I think the website is broken; inspecting the html elements (F12 in Chrome) shows a completely different color